# Page getting stuck on updating image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my web page which stops updating my image automatically. The page consists of a key pad. When a 4 digit code is entered the code is sent to alarm.php by ajax script. Alarm.php updated a Db and returns some values for alarmSet and alarm Triggered (0,0 alarm off, 1,0 alarm set, 1,1 alarm triggered). My index page then displays an icon depending on the returned values to show the state of the alarm. The page also has an auto update to check to Db and update the icons if the alarm state changes. All this works great. The console is showing the returned values and the image that is to be displayed and the page response as expected.
But if I leave the page for about 5 min the images stop updating. I can still enter a code, the Db is still updated and the console is still showing returned value eg 0,0 greenAlarm.jpg but the green icon is not displayed. It seems the page has locked on the display side. If I refresh the page all is ok again. I cant see what is causing this. Hope this make sense.

index JS script below which is in the Header part of the page

```js
<script>  // this script will get the data from alarm.php
 var count = 0;
 setInterval(function (){
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url:"alarm.php",
   data:"json",
   success: function(data){
    myObj = JSON.parse(data);  // pass the data returned to array myObject
    console.log(myObj)
    display(myObj);// send the data outside this function to be worked with
   }
  });
 }, 1000);
  //below function is needed to change a img depending on returned data from DB
  function display(){
  function image(thisImg){ // get image from if statements via return statement
   document.getElementById("image").src = thisImg; 
   console.log(thisImg);
  }
  if (myObj[0] == 0){
   image("greenAlarm.jpg"); // alarm off
   count = 0;
  }
  if (myObj[0] == 1 && myObj[1] == 0 && count < 2 || count > 3){
   image("blueAlarm.jpg");  // alarm set
   count = 0;
  }
  count = count + 1;
  console.log(count);
         // alarm triggered alternate between two images
  if (myObj[0] == 1 && myObj[1] == 1 && count == 2){
   image("alarmTrig1.jpg");
  }
  if (myObj[0] == 1 && myObj[1] == 1 && count == 3){
   count = 1;
   image("alarmTrig2.jpg");
  }
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addCode(key){
 var code = document.forms[0].code;
 if(code.value.length < 4){
  code.value = code.value + key;
 }
 if(code.value.length == 4){
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(alarm, 1000, code.value);
 }
}
function alarm(code){
 $.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "alarm.php",
   data: {code: code},
   cache: false,
   success: function(responseText) {
    console.log(responseText) // show returned text in console
   }
  })
  emptyCode();
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}
function submitForm(){
 document.forms[0].submit();
}

function emptyCode(){
 document.forms[0].code.value = "";
}
</script>
```

I also have gauges on the page the this is auto updated which works but not sure if this is locking up at the same time. I expect it is. This script is below and at the bottom of the main page

```js
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"data.php",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
    g1.refresh(data.Gwater);
    g2.refresh(data.Gsolar);
    g3.refresh(data.Grayburn);
    }
   });
  }, 3000)
  var g1 = new JustGage({
  id: "Gwater",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 75,
  label: "Hot Water",
  labelFontColor: "#00B1FF",
  valueFontColor: "#00B1FF",
  pointer:1
   });
    var g2 = new JustGage({
  id: "Gsolar",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  label: "Solar Temp",
  labelFontColor: "#00B1FF",
  valueFontColor: "#00B1FF",
  pointer:1
   });
   var g3 = new JustGage({
  id: "Grayburn",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  label: "Rayburn Temp",
  labelFontColor: "#00B1FF",
  valueFontColor: "#00B1FF",
  pointer:1
   });
</script>
```

I can upload all the code if needed.

Any help would be great thank you

Comment: is there a typing error at your `function display()` declaration, or is actually your used code because in ajax success you do this `display(myObj);` but your function declaration has no parameter

Comment: No typo error just my lack knowledge on functions. I passed myobj to the display function so I could use it. I can see what you mean and will need to change this. But it all works ok at first so not sure this is causing the lock up

Comment: I don't know how `myObj` even have a value inside `display()` maybe it's a  global array or something. Declare the `image()` function outside `display()`

Comment: Ok so I have updated the function display () to  function display(Jsonreturn) and updated the if statements to if (Jsonreturn[0] == 0). I assume this is correct, It still works I will have to see if it still locks up

Comment: This is all the script so it can be. I have only left out the HTML parts. The program is still getting locked. the console is showing 1,0 blueAlarm.jpg and count 1 but the page has the greenAlarm.jpg showing

Comment: try to output on the screen the src of the image that is changing not the image on success - just to see if the problem persist

Comment: I thought I was doing this with console.log(thisImg); this Img is being passed to the HTML element

Comment: On screen not console like this: document.createElement("<p>"+thisImg+"</p>"); not sure about the syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138961/discussion-between-stx-and-user2669997).

Comment: I will have a go at this later. Sorry but I have to go into work. I will pick this up again tonight. Thanks so far for the help

Comment: Could this be the page caching. Although the ajax is working in the back ground

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tHesTx/1tzyupos/1/) out; Also if you can provide a working example of your problem maybe I can help you - tell me if you encounter the same problem with this example doing what your doing(leaving the browser or whatever)

Comment: This is the program running http://steve8428.ddns.net/ I am looking at changing the setinterval to setTimout as it may be backing up on the server. I will try what you have written soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. It was the server getting overloaded with all the request and the page not updating. Below is the new code with a 10 second interval. I have taken the gauges out as this caused more problems. Tried using setTimeOut but could not get it to work properly. Anyway below code now works. Will have to design my own gauges now.

```js
<script>
 var gaugeData = function(){
  var response = 0;
   $.ajax({
   url:"data.php",
   dataType:"json",
   success: function(data){
    response = (data);
    console.log(response);
    if (response.id == 1){
    display(response);// send the data outside this function to be worked with
    } else{
     setTimeout (gaugeData, 5000);
    }
    }
   });
  }
  function display(data){
  console.log(data.AlarmSet);
  var thisImg = 0;
  if (data.AlarmSet == 0){
   thisImg = "greenAlarm.jpg"; // alarm off
  }
  if (data.AlarmSet == 1){
   thisImg = "blueAlarm.jpg"; // alarm on
  }
  $("#image").attr("src", thisImg);
  $("#Gwater").html(data.Gwater + '&deg;C');
  $("#Gsolar").html(data.Gsolar + '&deg;C');
  $("#Grayburn").html(data.Grayburn + '&deg;C');
  }
  setInterval (gaugeData, 10000);
</script>
```